# jQuery onclick hide/show divs in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, show-hide

I have a issue with some divs to hide/and show onclick.

I did this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/zL4h2dsL/

```
$(function() {
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    if (curPage.length) { 
        $("#"+curPage).hide();
    }
    curPage=$(this).data("page");
    $("#"+curPage).show();
});
});
```

It's all good but i need that when i click the second time on a link i hide the showed div, because now there is not a way to return at the all divs closed.

Someone can help me?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$(function() {
    var curPage="";
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
        if($("#"+page).css("display") != "none"){
            $("#"+page).slideUp();
        }else{
            $(".content").slideUp();
            $("#"+page).slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zL4h2dsL/3/

Comment: I agree with this, I preferred `.toggle` to `.slideToggle`, apples and oranges :)

Comment: Yes, with toggle i can close the div but i dont wont 2 divs opened at the same time...:(

Comment: Mh now if i re-click the opened link i hide for a moment but it return fast, there is not a way to close the div permanently?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to this [accordion menu](http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/mcgv4gok/).

You must check if the related element is already visible.

```
$(function() {
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var isVisible = false;
    if (curPage.length) {
        isVisible = $("#"+curPage).is(":visible"); 
        $("#"+curPage).hide();
    }
    if (!isVisible) {
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes works good! The only issue is that the html structure is not the same and it use jQueryUi...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class as a toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfyyrx7v/1/

```
if ($(this).hasClass("open")) { 
    $("#"+curPage).hide();
    $(this).removeClass("open");
} else {
    curPage=$(this).data("page");
    $("#"+curPage).show();
    $(this).addClass("open");
}
```

In the above I just add the open class to anything currently displaying and remove it the second time its clicked.

Comment: Yes, with toggle i can close the div but i dont wont 2 divs opened at the same time...:(